# How can I remove onmouseover Event onclick of a button LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, lwc-dom, js

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12 messagecontainer" onmouseover= {handleMouseOver} onmouseleave={handleMouseLeave}>
```

What I want is when I click a certain button I want to nullify the onMouseover functionality.

Is there any way we can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To nullify the **onMouseover** functionality in LWC, you can use a **boolean** variable to track the state of the button.

For example, you can declare a variable **isButtonClicked** in your JavaScript file and set it to false initially. Then, in your **handleMouseOver** function, you can check if **isButtonClicked** is `true` or `false`. If it is `true`, you can skip the mouseover logic. Otherwise, you can execute the mouseover logic as usual. Similarly, in your **handleButtonClick** function, you can set **isButtonClicked** to `true` when the button is clicked.

Here is a sample code snippet that illustrates this idea:

```
// YourComponent.js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class YourComponent extends LightningElement {
        isButtonClicked = false; // declare a boolean variable to track the button state

        handleMouseOver(event) {
                if (this.isButtonClicked) {
                        // skip the mouseover logic if the button is clicked
                        return;
                }
                // otherwise, execute the mouseover logic as usual
                // for example, change the background color of the div
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        }

        handleMouseLeave(event) {
                // reset the background color of the div
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = '';
        }

        handleButtonClick(event) {
                // set the button state to true when the button is clicked
                this.isButtonClicked = true;
                // do other things as needed
        }
}
```

.

```
<!-- YourComponent.html -->
<template>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12 messagecontainer"
        onmouseover={handleMouseOver}
        onmouseleave={handleMouseLeave}
        >
        This is a div with mouseover functionality
        </div>
        <button onclick={handleButtonClick}>Click me to nullify mouseover</button>
</template>
```

Comment: Thankyou Sir It worked for me :)